# A question on the relationship between two stabilizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-actions

I'm currently working on a homework question:

Let $G$ be a group. It acts on a set $X$. If $y=a\cdot x$ where $a\in G$, and $\exists g\in G$ s.t. $g\cdot y=y$ and $(a^{-1}ga)\cdot x=x$, how are the stabilizers of $x$ and $y$ related?

I know that when $G$ is abelian, the two stabilizers are identical. But what if the group is non-abelian, are they really related? I can't make any conclusions if this is not abelian.

Comment: The last clause is telling you that if $g$ stabilizes $y$, then $a^{-1}ga$ stabilizes $x$. So that tells you that if $H$ is the stabilizer of $y$, then $a^{-1}Ha$ is contained in the stabilizer or $x$. That should help you complete the problem.

Comment: Actually $g.y=y$ and $(a^{-1}ga).x = x$ are the same equality. And this implies that stabilizers of $x$ and $y$ are conjugate to each other.

Answer (score 1):

In general we have  $G_{ax} = a G_x a^{-1}$ since
$$g \in G_{ax} \iff gax = ax \iff a^{-1} ga x = x \iff a^{-1} g a \in G_x \iff g \in a G_x a^{-1}.$$

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Comment: Adding "[t]his is easy to prove in one line" but not actually doing it is kinda irritating to see. I think that's the reason for downvotes.

Comment: I have added the one line proof. First I didn't want to include it since every beginner should be able to find this proof by himself / herself. It is just a matter of using the definitions.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I was also confused by the downvote. I cancelled accepting your answer because of the downvotes......